# What are "degrees of freedom"?

Tags: degrees-of-freedom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to understand degrees of freedom?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16921/how-to-understand-degrees-of-freedom)

I was at a talk a few months back where the speaker used the term 'degrees of freedom'. She briefly said something along the lines of it meaning the number of values used to form a statistic that are free to vary.

What does this mean? I'm specifically looking for an intuitive explanation.